# How do I find a graphic card that suits a specific motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, compatibility

I want to search for a graphic card that suits my motherboard, but I don't know how!

For example, I have this [motherboard](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1218&MenuID=103&LanID=0), I don't know which type of graphic card should I search for.

How can I figure out what type of card I require?

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off topic.  That said, do you understand anything about the specifications detailed on the page you linked to?  The Specs clearly say "1 x PCI Express x16 Gen2.0 slot" which means you can get a PCI Express video card... which covers just about all current and modern video cards.  So based on the information you have provided (and have access to) you should search for a PCI Express video card.  I suspect however, that this is not what you meant, and that you want specific card recommendations.

Comment: @BonGart he is not exactly looking for recommendations so its not off topic

Comment: @Shakehar I hope you are right.  I did notice the OP asking for what type of card should be searched for, but since that information was in the specifications on the link the OP provided in the question, it felt like he was asking for more than just the type.

Comment: OP's asking how to pick the right card to fit, not asking which card he should buy, so it's not a product recommendation IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a site like [PC Part Picker](http://pcpartpicker.com/) where you specify your motherboard and then will only show you CPU's, graphics cards, and other components that are compatible. You can also do some research about the specific motherboard and learn what expansion slots it has. After that knowledge is found you can research graphics cards based on the size of your case, size of your PSU, and support for PCI Express 2.0 or PCI Express 3.0. You can read more about PCI Express [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express).